# Error al usar pythonanywhere

Tags: python

Estoy tratando de montar un proyecto en www.pythonanywhere.com pero al instalar las librerias necesarias para que funcione me sale este error y la verdad es que no entiendo porque si alguien tiene idea se agradece mucho la ayuda u orientacion.

Ejecuto el comando pip install py_expression_eval el cual pues funciona a la perfeccion en cualquier pc en el que lo intente siempre y cuando este instalado python 3 o mas, pero al hacer el mismo comando en esa pagina me sale este error[image: error]

creo que el error esta en la forma en que estoy haciendo la instalacion del modulo no estoy seguro

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para poder instalar nuevos módulos en tu usuario de ***pythonanywhere.com*** debes usar la bandera `--user`.

Por ejemplo, si deseas instalarlo para Python 3.6 debes hacer:

```
pip3.6 install --user py_expression_eval
```

Un ejemplo real de uso:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si estas usando el intérprete por defecto (Python 2.7) no necesitas obligatoriamente especificar la versión:

```
pip install --user py_expression_eval
```

Otra opción es usar un `virtualenv` e instalarlo dentro, en ese caso no se necesita de la bandera `--user`. Para más imformación sobre la instalación de módulos mirate la sección de [Ayuda](https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/InstallingNewModules/)  de la web.

**Edición:** la bandera `--user` se usa tal cual, es literal. No se sustituye por el nombre de usuario que tengamos ni se agrega el nombre de usuario en la linea de comando en ningún momento.

Comment: una duda sevilla que creo que es obvio que si pero en la parte que pones --user el user lo cambio por el nombre de mi usuario simplemente? es que aun no lo he probado pero apenas pueda te aviso, muchas gracias deverdad

Comment: No, no debes cambiarlo por nada. Se usa tal cual. La propia ayuda lo dice, textualmente: _**'Please note, this is quite literally `--user`, you don't need to replace it with your username, or to add your username to the command line!'**_. He editado la respuesta porque tal como dices es confuso. Saludos.

Comment: Vale muchas gracias :D @FJSevilla

Comment: Solo vine para decir que si funciono con esto Sevilla gracias!